# Plot of Keras Classifier Model performance over epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the built-in KerasClassifier wrapper to perform kfold cross-validation on a practice neural network to classify the famous "Iris Dataset." I would like to create a plot of the model's performance over time. I am not sure how to do this with the KerasClassifier wrapper.

model.history() method

```py
### Neural Network Time!
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

### Build small model
def small_network():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

small_estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=small_network, epochs=50, verbose=0)
small_results = cross_val_score(small_estimator, X, y_hot, cv=kfold)
print("Small Network Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (small_results.mean()*100, small_results.std()*100))
#GRAPH OF MODEL HISTORY!!!
```

I expect to be able to create a graph of model accuracy over time with the KerasClassifier object.

Comment: As far as I understand the variable small_results should contain a dictionary of the values, which could easily be plotted. What does small_results contain in your case?

Answer (score -2):

just use after running your validation:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=small_results)
```

then you can customise the plot